# why ambiguous occured in the case of bellow code while overloading the area function

Tags: c++, overriding

I overloaded the area function. like this 
float area(int v,int u);
float area(float r,float s);
then I called the area function with the arguments 2.3,4.4 
but there shows a error
call of overloaded 'area(double, double)' is ambiguous
but I don't understand what is the reason for ambiguous as here it is clear that 2.3 and 4.4 are float type then call the second version of area 
float area(float r,float s);
someone explain the reason of occurring  ambiguous in this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float area(int v,int u)
{
    return 0*v*u;
}
float area(float r,float s)
{

    return r*s;
}
int main()
{
    cout << area(2.3,4.4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `2.3` is double, `2.2f` would be float, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments in the area call are of type double, not float. The compiler can not decide if it should convert them to float or to int. The following will work as expected:

```
cout << area(2.3f,4.4f);
```

In this case the values passed to area are floats, not doubles.

Comment: Better still would be to rewrite the function to use `double`. There's not much reason to use `float` in C++. `Float` is less precise and often slower than using `double`.

Comment: @john: The use of float versus double does not depend on the language but on the problem you are solving. OpenGL uses float a lot. Point clouds use floats to save space (LAS format).